# How to remove square brackets when rendering dictionary items in django

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I am working on a django project whereby I am saving values to the database of a Model instance. The project is a resume parser which seems to be getting the values as a dictionary. I have succesfully saved the data but when rendering the output does not look good as it renders with the square brackets and quotes. Is there a way I can render them as a list?
Here is my models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_images')
    bio = models.TextField()
    resume        = models.FileField('Upload Resumes', upload_to='resumes/', null=True, blank=True,default='resume.docx')
    name          = models.CharField('Name', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    email         = models.CharField('Email', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    mobile_number = models.CharField('Mobile Number',  max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    education     = models.CharField('Education', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    skills        = models.CharField('Skills', max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    company_name  = models.CharField('Company Name', max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    college_name  = models.CharField('College Name', max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    designation   = models.CharField('Designation', max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    experience    = models.CharField('Experience', max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    total_experience  = models.CharField('Total Experience (in Years)', max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    whatsapp       = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    facebook       = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    twitter       = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    linkedin       = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    languages    = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

My views.py

```
@login_required
def myprofile(request, user_id):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(id=user_id)
    context = {'profile':profile}
    return render(request, 'user/profile.html', context)
```

The template;

```
{% for skill in user.profile.skills %}
  {{skill}} 
{% endfor %}
```

And here is how they are rendered:

```
[ ' S y s t e m ' , ' S p a n i s h ' , ' P u b l i c r e l a t i o n s ' , ' E n g l i s h ' , ' A d v e r t i s i n g ' , ' A d m i n i s t r a t i o n ' , ' D e p o s i t s ' , ' R e s e a r c h ' , ' P h o t o s h o p ' , ' C o m m u n i c a t i o n ' , ' E x c e l ' , ' W o r d ' , ' P o w e r p o i n t ' , ' N e w s p a p e r ' , ' M a r k e t i n g ' ]
```

I have tried using `', '.join()` but still it does not render them as a list

Comment: What are you expecting as output? (the extra spaces are what jump out at me as being problematic, TBH)

Comment: The skills property here is just one item, I can assume you are entering the list as one entry. the easy way is to create another model for the Skills, then add ManyToMany to the profile. Then you will be able to loop.

There is another way, to use Array field, but it would be more complicated

Comment: Could you share how to use the manytomany field please. I am still new to django

Comment: ArrayField is only an option if you have a Postgres database. Another option would be a simple `JSONField`, or the M2M relationship as mentioned above.

Comment: Hello. The JSONField idea worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The 'skills' field in your 'Profile' model is a character field. Hence, meaning that its use is to store string values. To be able to store multiple skills associated with a profile, using a separate model class for skills is what you should try implementing.

In your **models.py** file, define the new model (make sure to remove the skills field from the Profile model) :

```
class Skills(models.Model):
    skill= models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    profile_id = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Every time you create a new profile object, update the skills associated with that profile before saving them. Now to get your skills to output properly in your template, your **views.py** could look like this:

```
@login_required
def myprofile(request, user_id):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(id=user_id)
    profile_skills = Skills.objects.get(profile_id=profile.id)
    context = {'profile':profile, 'skills': profile_skills}
    return render(request, 'user/profile.html', context)
```

Now your template will obviously look like this:

```
{% for skill in skills %}
  {{skill}} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hello. I used the ides of changing the CharField into JSONField and it worked. Thanks for your response